# Is their any way to not close the soft keyboard when the EditText loose the focus?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have 2 views, on each views i have an editText. My problem is that when i move the focus from one editText to the other then the soft keyboard is hide and show and this is a little annoying. i would like to force the keyboard to not be hidden (to be immediately show again) if the focus is moved to another EditText.

Is their anyway to tell the soft keyboard to not hide when the editText loose the focus (and to bind later the soft Keyboard to the other edittext who have now the focus)

Comment: I wondering your xml option for EditText

Comment: i don't have any xml, i create the EditText programmatically

Comment: I tested it. I make two EditText and input it. but softkeyboard is not hide.

Answer (score 0):

Register a callback to be invoked when focus of this view changed.
and show keyboard

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener: The callback that will run.
```

Show keyboard

```
public void showKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View v = getCurrentFocus();
    if (v != null)
        imm.showSoftInput(v, 0);
}
```

Comment: i already do like this, the problem is that the keyboard will be first close and them immediately opened again :(